# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to secure Web Service using JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have only used JWT for user login authentication. But I have this different task.

I am using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API to implement a Web Service whereby customers will be able to print invoices.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInvoice()
{
    List<Invoice> Items = await _context.Invoice.ToListAsync();
    int Count = Items.Count();
    return Ok(new { Items, Count });
}
```

It is given to the customer like this:

```
https://invoicewebservice.com/api/myinvoice
```

as a web service. The Web Service will be provided to the customers.

I want to secure the Web Service given to the customers using **JWT**, so that anybody cannot just view it. But there will be no username and password (I am familiar with this).

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I sound harsh or rude but have you tried searching on google "asp.net core web api jwt"? You can find many tutorials. This website is for asking questions when stuck on a specific problem, not to give a whole tutorial.

Comment: follow this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM1fPt1BcLc&t=52s

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - You have still not understood me. I have done JWT for Login. But this time around no login and user registration. I just want to use it to protect the url, so that anybody cannot just use it, but only the parties that have the JWT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have done JWT for Login. But this time around no login and user registration. I just want to use it to protect the url, so that anybody cannot just use it, but only the parties that have the JWT.

From your description, you have already implemented JWT Authentication in Web API.
To make the GetInvoice method only accessed by the request which have the valid JWT, you can add the `[Authorize]` attribute on the GetInvoice method or its API controller. This means if the token is missing or faulty then web api methods will not be initiated. While for proper tokens the Web API will be authorized to the request.

Code like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInvoice()
{
    List<Invoice> Items = await _context.Invoice.ToListAsync();
    int Count = Items.Count();
    return Ok(new { Items, Count });
}
```

Refer to [Implement JWT In .NET Core API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-jwt-in-net-core-api/) and [How to Implement JWT Authentication in Web API Using .Net 6.0, Asp.Net Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-in-web-api-using-net-6-0-asp-net-core/)